# Easiest Way to Reorder a sequence

Tags: c#, linq

Consider 4 (say up to 100) instances of class A, in List which has an int property Order.

```
a0.Order is 0
a1.Order is 1
a2.Order is 2
a3.Order is 3
```

Now the Order property needs to be changed so that a0 is inserted before a3 (or at any index in the list - could be at start, end or middle.)

The result should be this:

```
a0.Order is 2
a1.Order is 0
a2.Order is 1
a3.Order is 3
```

Note this is a List, and the actual physical order of the list does not matter, only that the properties are changed.

The number of items is not changing just the "order".

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Define best? Fastest, quickest to program, easiest to understand?

Comment: How big is the list?  Small lists (even less than a few thousand), or even slightly bigger lists that don't change all that often, probably aren't worth optimizing for for efficiency in algorithm.

Comment: Max 100 items.  Easiest to understand.

Comment: Are a0, a1, a2, etc local variables? Or are these guys all in an array? or what? Is that what you meant by "note this is a list", that the elements are actually `a[0]`, `a[1]` etc of a list?

Comment: They are actually Entities from the EntityFramework.  ListEntity is the parent, which has a related list of ListItemEntity.  The ListItemEntity has a Sorted property which is what I need to reorder.  It is used to show the list in the order the user wants.

Comment: When you say that the element must be inserted "between a2 and a3", is it always the case that `a2.Order + 1 == a3.Order`?

Comment: What if the user wants to insert the element at position zero? Or the last position? Neither of those are *between* anything.  (The usual way to solve this problem is to rather than say "insert between these two items", you say "insert before this index", and are allowed to specify an index that is one greater than the usual maximum if you want it at the end.)

Comment: The point of all these questions is that the problem is pretty underspecified as you've given it, and therefore it is difficult to write a correct solution.

Comment: @EricLippert Good point, hadn't thought of that.  Yes, it could be before or after.  Will update the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Order property should not be an integer but a decimal. You can easily change the value and then sort by it to retrieve the items in any arbitrary order.  The new value is the midpoint between the preceding and following values.

P.S. Then you only have to change the Order property for the item(s) in the list you want to reposition.

Comment: yes, this was the answer - once I started using an decimal instead, the sorting was quite easy.

Comment: doesn't this have a pretty limited scope? With the first move you would already have 1 decimal (i.e. between 2 and 3: 2.5), with a second move you could get 2.75, then 2.875 etc. You quickly will run out of digits.

Comment: @DirkBoer: Would you care to work out how quickly?  If you do run out of digits then just re-number all of them.

Comment: "In SQL Server, the default maximum precision of numeric and decimal data types is 38." It seems like if you have (very) bad luck you introduce an extra digit for every reorder. That could mean that you could run out of digits around 38 reorders? 

But I might be missing something in my reasoning :)

Comment: @DirkBoer But you could be smarter, you don't have to exactly halve the interval, instead you could use something like 2.5, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 2.95, 2.97, … Or you could say that the half doesn't have to be computed exactly. So if you had only 2 decimals, 2.88 would be good enough replacement for the exact 2.875. Or you could use `float`, where each halving takes just a single bit.

Comment: True, but as the question states 'easiest to understand' I'd go for the four lines of code in my answer and be done with it ;) And now give me my points!! j/k ;p

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this:

```
void MoveAndUpdateOrder(List<A> list, A item, int positionToInsert)
{
    // Order elements
    var ordered_list = list.OrderBy(a => a.Order).ToList();

    // Remove and insert at the proper position
    ordered_list.Remove(item);
    ordered_list.Insert(positionToInsert, item);

    // Update the Order properties according to it's current index
    for ( int i = 0; i < ordered_list.Count; i++ )
        ordered_list[i].Order = i;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var a0 = new A { Order = 0 };
var a1 = new A { Order = 1 };
var a2 = new A { Order = 2 };
var a3 = new A { Order = 3 };

var list = new List<A>
{
    a0, a1, a2, a3
};

MoveAndUpdateOrder( list, a0, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3):

We have to differentiate between moving an element upwards (to the end) or downwards (to the beginning of the list). Let's define two order numbers `i` and `k` where `i < k`.

**Move element `i` upwards to `k`**:
The orders below `i` and above `k` are not affected.
The orders `i+1 ... k` are decreased by one and `i` becomes `k`.

```
A moving = list.Where(a => a.Order == i);
foreach (A x in list.Where(a => a.Order > i && a.Order <= k)
{
    x.Order--;
}
moving.Order = k;
```

**Move element `k` downwards to `i`**:
The orders below `i` and above `k` are not affected.
The orders `i ... k-1` are increased by one and `k` becomes `i`.

```
A moving = list.Where(a => a.Order == k);
foreach (A x in list.Where(a => a.Order >= i && a.Order < k)
{
    x.Order++;
}
moving.Order = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to I would number them with gaps in between:

```
a0.Order is 10
a1.Order is 20
a2.Order is 30
a3.Order is 40
```

This way you can simple reorder by picking a number within a gab.

```
a0.Order is 35
a1.Order is 20
a2.Order is 30
a3.Order is 40
```

After some iterations you may have no gabs left at some insertion point. With 100 items you can simple reset all the order numbers to have equal gabs again.

Comment: Possible, but not really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just keep the items in a list and imply the `Order` property from the physcial order of the items in the list?

Given an `Item` class *without* an order  property, like so:

```
class Item
{
    public readonly string Value;

    public Item(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

You could write a simple collection class for `Items` which has a `Move()` method to let you move an item from one index to another:

```
class Items: IEnumerable<Item>
{
    private readonly List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();

    public void Add(Item item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _items.Count; }
    }

    public void Move(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    {
        Item item = _items[oldIndex];
        _items.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
        _items.Insert(newIndex, item);
    }

    IEnumerator<Item> IEnumerable<Item>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

You can use `Items` like so:

```
var items = new Items
{
    new Item("a0"),
    new Item("a1"),
    new Item("a2"),
    new Item("a3")
};

// ...

items.Move(0, 2); // Move the item at index 0 to index 2.
```

Then when you need the `Order` you can synthesize it from the list's physical order like so:

```
var orderedItems = items.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Order = index});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the algorithm for You, that uses sorting and LinkedList collection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OrderExample {

    public class A {
        public int Order { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Program {

        // Change order so that a is ordered between b and c.
        public static void SetOrder(List<A> list, A a, A b, A c) {
            list.Sort((x, y) => x.Order.CompareTo(y.Order));
            var linkedList = new LinkedList<A>(list);
            var bNode = linkedList.Find(b);
            if (bNode != null) {
                linkedList.Remove(a);
                linkedList.AddAfter(bNode, a);
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var value in linkedList) {
                    value.Order = i++;
                }                
            }
        }

        static void Main() {
            var a0 = new A {Order = 0};
            var a1 = new A {Order = 1};
            var a2 = new A {Order = 2};
            var a3 = new A {Order = 3};
            var list = new List<A> {a0, a1, a2, a3};

            SetOrder(list, a0, a2, a3);
            foreach (var a in list) {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(a.Order);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```